# How to connect css file in flask?? In there in different Syntex?

Tags: python, css, flask

Hello i have one code but don't know how to connect css in flask.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`
But its not working. Is there any difference Syntex in flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make one folder as 'static' and make one more folder for css files so that you can put css file in that folder.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">`